# Jave Script format value date adding leading 0 to hour

Tags: javascript

i have a value of "08-28-2021 1:00:00 pm" is in  $('#strDinnerStartTime').val)

i need to format it "08-28-2021 01:00:00 pm"  where the hour is not just 1 but 01.

how can i do this thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: i try but no - this is what i got   $('.timepicker-no-seconds').timepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
            minuteStep: 1,
            defaultTime: false
        });

Comment: what does `$('.timepicker-no-seconds'). .....` have to do with formatting the date in that link?

Comment: `.replace(/\s([1-9])/, ' 0$1')`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The format that your date/time string is in is not recognized by javascript's built-in `Date.parse()` function.  So, you may need to fallback to 'disassembling' the date/time string, formatting the hours with leading-zero padding, then 'reassembling' the date/time string, like so:

```js
var s = "08-28-2021 1:00:00 pm";

var datepart = s.split(' ')[0];
var timepart1 = s.split(' ')[1];
var timepart2 = s.split(' ')[2];

var hours = timepart1.split(':')[0];
var minutes = timepart1.split(':')[1];
var seconds = timepart1.split(':')[2];

var hoursstr = String(hours).padStart(2, '0');
var minutesstr = String(minutes).padStart(2, '0');
var secondsstr = String(seconds).padStart(2, '0');

var result = datepart + ' ' + hoursstr + ':' + minutesstr + ':' + secondsstr + ' ' + timepart2;
console.log(result); //produces 08-28-2021 01:00:00 pm
```

Comment: this is a long winded way of doing `result = s.replace(/\d+/g, s => s.padStart(2, '0'))`

Comment: That's a nifty one-liner you have there, @Bravo!

Comment: May I suggest using `const`/`let` to encourage better practices? 